# How to get today and this month count of records as single table?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Query for today's records:**

```
SELECT FIELD1, COUNT(1) AS "TODAY_COUNT" FROM TABLE1 
WHERE DATEFIELD >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) 
GROUP BY FIELD1;
```

**Query for current month records:**

```
SELECT FIELD1, COUNT(1) AS "THIS_MONTH_COUNT" FROM TABLE1 WHERE 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) AND
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
GROUP BY FIELD1;
```

Need to display two values in single `SELECT` statement.

How can i achieve this efficiently?

**Expected output:**

```
----------------------------------------
|FIELD1|today_count | This_month_count |
----------------------------------------
| NAME1|         10 |              3442|
| NAME2|         15 |              4342|
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Add first select as additional select column:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS "THIS_MONTH_COUNT" ,
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE1 WHERE DATEFIELD >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)) AS "TODAY_COUNT"
FROM TABLE1 WHERE 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) AND
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'Sysdate' in your table a `date` column? If so:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(
        CASE            
           WHEN DATEFIELD = cast(getdate() as Date)             
           THEN 1           
           ELSE NULL        
    END) AS TodayCount,     
    COUNT(      
         CASE           
           WHEN DATEFIELD BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()          
           THEN 1           
           ELSE NULL        
    END) AS MonthCount
FROM Table
```

Comment: `SYSDATE` is system date and `DATEFIELD` is my `date` column

Comment: Edited with your datefield - I don't think you'd need sysdate in this instance? Try the above!

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  FIELD1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEFIELD >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) today_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN 
          EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) 
          AND 
          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATEFIELD) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)) 
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END) This_month_count  
FROM TABLE1  
GROUP BY FIELD1;
```

Comment: Is `FROM TABLE1` removed wantedly or by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Using `decode` by summing up the related days might be a short and clean approach :

```
select field1,
       sum(decode(to_char(datefield,'yyyymm'),to_char(sysdate,'yyyymm'),1,0)) as "This month's count",
       sum(decode(sign(trunc(datefield)-trunc(sysdate)+1),1,1,0)) as "Today's count"
  from table1 t
 group by field1;
```